# Import Python file from another directory raises ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, directory, package, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I want to import a python file from another directory. I can import the stuff but it can't find those dependencies in the python file and raises me the `ModuleNotFoundError` exception. These trees might help:

```
app1:
   pkgs/
   main.py
app2:
   script.py
```

Here is the `app1/main.py` file:

```
from pkgs import *

def main():
    ...
```

I want to import `app1/main.py` file from `app2/script.py` and run the `main()` function and this is what I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgs'
```

It can import it but it's unable to import the `pkgs/*`.

Answer (score 0):

you need `__init__.py` (empty file) in `app1` and in `app2`. The init file makes python treat directories as python modules.